# How to pass a list of objects to server?

Tags: jquery, struts2

In my jsp page I have an javascript function inside which I have a Iterator.On each iteration I need to store data into an object and after the completion of the iteration , the list of objects need to be passed to the sever which is to be saved to DataBase

Comment: can you show your JSP code, else it will be a hit and trial answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your must serialize your objects, send them to action and deserialize them. For example, use json.

1 Create a JSON string from each object. Your can use [JSON-js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) or Jquery [jquery-json](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/downloads/detail?name=jquery.json-2.3.js&can=2&q=) plugin or thomesing else.

2 Send them to your action

```
  var data = {"myObjects", Json_string_1, 
              "myObjects", Json_string_2,
              .........e.t.c.............}
  $.post("/path/myAction.do", data, function(){
    ....... do thomesing........................
  })
```

3 In your action create String array parameter. Parameter interceptor will put all your Json_string in that array

```
private String[] myObjects = new String[];

public void setMyObjects(String[] myObjects) {
  this.myObjects = myObjects;
}
```

4 Create objects from Json strings. Use [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or whatever your want

Answer (score 0):

You will need to serialize your objects in awhatever format you feel comfortable with and then send (POST) the text to the server where you can deserialize it again and work with the data.